# Persisting event.clientX value in setTimeout callback function

Tags: javascript, events, closures, dom-events

I have this routine which is called `onmouseover` of a certain element. I want there to be a slight delay - i.e. give the user time to `mouseout` before the effect takes place. The effect uses the `event.clientX` value. However it appears that by the time the callback is called - after 500ms - the `event` object no longer exists. How can I neatly persist the state of `event.clientX`?

```
function showTip(sDivID){
    SHOW_TIP_TIMEOUT_ID = setTimeout(function(){
        var div = $('#'+sDivID).show()[0];
        div.style.left = event.clientX;
    } ,500)
}
```

Comment: I don't see event defined in that code, what is it's scope and where is it coming from?

Comment: @Robert I believe it's part of the DOM though differs from browser to browser. I'm developing mainly for Internet Exploder 8. [Ref - Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)

Comment: no, it's not part of the DOM; it's a `window` property in IE browsers but not any other browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're relying on this only working in Internet Explorer, you can just save the value before setting up the timeout:

```
function showTip(sDivID) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  SHOW_TIP_TIMEOUT_ID = setTimeout(function() {
    var div = $('#' + sDivId).show()[0];
    div.style.left = x;
  }, 500);
}
```

If you want this to work for other browsers, you'll have to grab the event in the event handler itself and either pass it around or else stash it in a global (ick).  Since you're using jQuery, it already does all the browser normalization work for you, so you should take advantage of that.

Comment: It's sad to see web development going on with a single browser as a target, when it's really not hard to create more generally-usable software.

Comment: I know, it is sad - but I work in an organisation that has only IE (and IE6 up until a couple of months ago) - and the installation of other browsers on our machines is prevented. Whadoesaguydo?

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. Still, it's sad, in a general sort of way. I don't blame you personally :-)

Answer (score 1):

Event object is global in IE. A potential quick resolution for all browsers - if you're just using the clientX integer and not the complete event object then store only the integer.  Something like:

```
function showTip(sDivID, savedClientX){
    SHOW_TIP_TIMEOUT_ID = setTimeout(function(){
        var div = $('#'+sDivID).show()[0];
        div.style.left = savedClientX;
    } ,500)
}
```

Comment: The event object is only global in Internet Explorer, not in other browsers.

Comment: I was hoping I might be able to do it without changing the call signature of `showTip()`...

Comment: @Pointy: Thanks-clarified IE usage.  
@El Ronnoco: I'll let somebody else create an answer about how to do it without changing the sig, and will leave my answer here for posterity.